# postfix master dead but subsys locked but working

Tags: centos, postfix

postfix master dead but subsys locked

I tried removing the files on /var/lock/subsys/ and restarted postfix, no error on logs and mail is working but when I check the postfix status it still says "master dead but subsys locked"

2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.i686

```
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                      *:*                         LISTEN      21290/master
```

checking on status:

```
[root@smtp subsys]# service postfix status
master dead but subsys locked
[root@smtp subsys]#
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with stopping or disabling the exim service because postfix can conflict with exim when both software were running.

```
#service postfix stop
#rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/postfix
#rm -rf  /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
#service exim stop
#chkconfig exim off
#service postfix start
```

Your postfix will be running without dead.

Comment: I updated the wording somewhat, please revert if I missed your intent.

Comment: Lifesaver.  Another program had installed exim (and used chkconfig to make it always run). Turned it off & disabled it... postfix running like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the root volume space. If space is not available try to move or delete data from the root path then forward to fire commands like

- service condor start
- systemctl start condor.